# Seven Segment display output problem

Tags: display

I am trying to come up with a circuit using logic gates to drive a seven segment display.

I have a circuit with a BCD output (A, B, C, D) and need to convert this so that when any one of nine buttons are pushed, they produce a number.

The circuit needs to display a 0 when nothing is pressed. However, when buttons 1 - 9 are presesed it needs to display 7, 4, 8, 0, 5, 6, 8, 8, 9, respectively.

I have produced truth tables and k-maps, which all seem to be correct. But, it does not seem to be working at all. I get random numbers and a couple of odd displays of random elements on the display (not numbers or letters).

If anyone can point me in the right direction, or give me some advice, I would be eternally grateful!

[image]

Comment: I've made the circuit easier to read. If I've screwed up then sorry.

Answer (score 1):

It's not clear why you're going via BCD. Just create the combinational logic directly.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fZvsOH.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 1. Pressing a switch turns on the segments connected by small signal diodes.*

Comment: I am converting from BCD...

Comment: @NickH yes your circuit shows this but why bother - interface directly with the buttons and cut-out the clutter.

Answer (score 0):

To be honest: I can't take the time debugging your circuit. I just wanted to point out that I would have approached the functionality different.

Use a 7447 decoder and re-arrange the button order so button 1 is connected to input 7, button 2 to 4 etc.
For number 8 put two button in parallel.

Comment: Yeah, I have initially used a 7447N, and this worked perfectly for what I initially needed, now I want to remove the 7447N and use just logic gates to produce the desired result to depen my understanding. 
Thank you for the input though.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely the issue would be caused if aren't accounting for the fact that the buttons and LEDs are inverted.

When the button is pressed, the input value will be a 0.

When the output is a 1, the LED segment will be off.

Comment: That was something that occured to me after quite some time... I have accounted for that, and changed the circuit accordingly. Accounting for it, allowed me to get close to acheiving what I want, but still "no cigar".